# Gunicorn is not binding my domain by using ".sock" file

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to host multiple sites on VPS using sock file but the problem is that I can't see the website up and running using gunicorn sock. But I can't see my website live. I need to know how do I change the following screen showing my app binds with particular port instead of sock file or if it has to be a sock file then why I can't see it in browser at mydomain.com.

Gunicorn upscript is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="dressika"                                     # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/django/mydomain      # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/django/mydomain/run/gunicorn.sock         # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=django                                         # the user to run as
GROUP=django                                        # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                       # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mydomain.settings            # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=mydomain.wsgi                    # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

With above settings gunicorn startup script runs fine but I couldn't see my site live on browser or client end. I guess I need to bind it with some port. I am not sure if my assumption is correct. My app settings.py shows in `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['mydomain.com', 'www.mydomain.com]`. Still the url isn't working.

My Nginx settings are:

```
upstream mydomain_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9500 fail_timeout=0;

}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;


    root /home/django/mydomain;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;



    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|woff2|woff|ttf)$ {
        expires 365d;

    }



    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/mydomain/media/;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location static/static-only {
        alias /home/django/mydomain/static-only/; 

    }
    # Django static images
    location /static/mydomain/images {
        alias /home/django/mydomain/static-only/images/;
    }


    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin;
    }

    location / {


        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://mydomain_server;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60s;

    }
}
```

I've also tried binding `/home/django/mydomain/run/gunicorn.sock` with upstream server instead of IP:Port but still couldn't see the site up and running.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. did you or anyone get a workaround for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, `.sock` doesn't create. This method helps me. 
Prerequests:

1. Installed nginx: when you type in browser 127.0.0.1 - obtain "Wellcome to nginx...".
2. You install python2 or 3 no matter, and other stuffs: pip, django, gunicorn...
3. You installed and settled virtualenv. (in my case, I use virtualenvwrapper - this is good staffs, saves all you env in one folder: `/home/user/.virtualenvs/`)
4. You created django project, and when: python manage.py runserver - 
   you obtain "It works..." - this good news.
5. When you type gunicorn `--bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application` - you have the same result, as a step 4.

Next step for setting you dj.project throgh gunicorn to nginx:

1. You create file in `/etc/systemd/system/any_file_name.service` - you can named this file as you want, at [DO](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)  - it names as `gunicorn.service`.

my method:

```
$cd /etc/systemd/system

$sudo touch gunicorn.service
```

and open it your favorite text editor

```
$sudo subl gunicorn.service
```

2. Inside it you write:

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=gunicorn daemon
> After=network.target
>
> [Service]
> User=vetal
> Group=www-data
> WorkingDirectory=/var/www/apple.net
> ExecStart=/home/vetal/.virtualenvs/univ/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/apple.net/mysite/mysite.sock mysite.wsgi:application
>  [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

ExecStart - what will be started by nginx, when your virualenv will be turned off. Do you remember, gunicorn was install through pip, when your env was turn on ? 
-- bind unix:... - this address WHERE your .sock will created! Pay attention for this!

CHECK EVERY LETTER!TWISE!!! (of course with you links..)

3. Type:

> $ls -l

if you see in attributes to your 'gunicorn.service' something:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Янв 12 11:48 gunicorn.service
```

this means - this file is not executable, and you `.sock` - file will never created! Make next:

```
$sudo chmod 755 gunicorn.service
```

and check:

```
$ls -l
```

if you get:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  305 Янв 11 19:48 gunicorn.service
```

this good! Everything allright!

4. Then you created nginx block, in /etc/nginx/site-available/ it likes next:

> ```
> server {
>     listen 80;
>     root /var/www/apple.net;
>
>     server_name apple.net;
>     location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
>
>     location = /static/ {
>             alias /var/www/apple.net/static/;
>     }
>     location / {
>             include proxy_params;
>             proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/apple.net/mysite/mysite.sock;
>     } }
> ```

Notice: proxy_pass - must be identicaly correct with folder where `.sock` file created in gunicorn.service!

5. Copies this file to `/sites-enable`

   $ sudo cp /etc/nginx/site-avaliable/apple.net /etc/nginx/site-enable
6. I don't have any domaine, so I modify my `/etc/hosts` file, add row:

> 127.0.0.10   apple.net

6. Very important steps!!!

`$pkill gunicorn`  - this step kill daemon, which you may started before. gunicorn in this case, means name of file which you created before with .service extention, in `/etc/systemd/system` - folder.

7. Start gunicorn.service daemon:

> ```
> $sudo systemctl start gunicorn
>
> $sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
> ```

8. Start(or restart nginx)

> $sudo /etc/init.d/nginx (re)start

9. Check your domane name in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since gunicorn is running on a socket, you need to bind to that socket, not to a port, in the upstream section.

```
upstream mydomain_server {
    server unix:/home/django/mydomain/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned above I tried this already and its not working for me. Wokers do start like normal with no errors with script but mysite is not presented. I can access my website by executing simple gunicorn command from terminal like "gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:9500 mydomain.wsgi:application" and my website shows up but not with the sock file. Is it necessary to bind with sock file or can I simply bind with IP:Port? If with port I can bind a website in production then what changes I need to make in script?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your questions. If it works with a port, you should use the port.

Answer (score 0):

I have nginx serving up a .sock file from gunicorn. My typical gunicorn call looks like this:

```
exec gunicorn \
    --pid /web/gunicorn.pid \
    --workers '4' \
    --name myapp \
    --chdir /src/myapp \
    --bind unix:/web/.sock \
    --log-file=- \
    myapp.wsgi:application
```

My nginx conf for `/` looks like this; the main difference seems to be that your proxy_pass statement doesn't point to the .sock file:

```
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://unix:/web/.sock;
    }
```